# How to push list of object ids from another query into an array attribute of a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

What I need is something like:

```
db.categories.update(
                { _id: ObjectId("52824e116a4dec0000000004") },
                { $push: { scores: { $each : db.products.find({"category": ObjectId("51cedfb29b33fc0800000015")})} }
              )
```

Do I need ORM tool for this? Or can I do with shell?

Comment: You want to read about $pushAll: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to use JavaScript in the shell. It might look something like this:

```
// not sure what your schema looks like, but you'll want your find to
// get you the right documents and format
var ids = db.products.find({"category": ObjectId("51cedfb29b33fc0800000015")});

db.categories.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("52824e116a4dec0000000004") },
    { $pushAll: { scores: ids } 
    }
);
```

You'll have to make sure that `ids` is an array of object ids. The current `find` you have looks like it will return the entire documents. If you need more guidance, I'd suggest adding your schema to your question as well.